# Is this proof that the compositum of splitting fields is a splitting field correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

I'm thinking about the following claim:

Let $k^a$ be an algebraic closure of $k$, and let $K_i$ be a splitting field of $f_i$ in $k^a$ (the algebraic closure of $k$). Then the compositum of the $K_i$ is a splitting field for our family.

I wanted to prove this as follows. Let us remark that the compositum is defined as $$K:=k^a\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} K_i\right)$$ But then clearly $$f_i(X)=c\prod_{i\in I}(X-\alpha_i)$$ where $\alpha_i\in K$ by definiton and $K$ is generated by all the roots of all $f_i$. So $K$ is indeed a splitting field.

So now my first question is, does this work?

My second is why do we need $k^a$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Is this prove" $\to$ "is this proof"

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I don't understand your comment

Comment: "to prove" is a verb, and "the proof" is a noun.

Comment: ah but you can't help me with my problem?

Comment: $\Pi K_i$, being a direct product of fields, is not a field. That's the wrong symbol.

Comment: We need $k^a$, the algebraic closure of $k$ to specify in which field all the roots are located. It is possible that a field $k$ has more than one algebraic closure and then the splitting field would look different from the one in $k^a$. Here the important thing for this to work is that all splitting fields, the $K_i$ and $K$ are viewed as subsets of the same algebraic closure $k^a$.

Comment: @Lukas so my proof is not correct?

Comment: $k^a\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} K_i\right)$ is a nonsense.

Comment: @reuns but I think that's the definition from Wikipedia, isn't it?

Comment: The proof is basically correct, just the few notation things other people mentioned are not optimal. In my way of notation $k^a(\bigcup_{i \in I} K_i)$ would be a field extension of $k^a$ - but you actually want to say that you are looking at a field extension of the "ground field" $k$. And the direct product $\prod_{i \in I} K_i$ is not the compositum. The compositum is the smallest field containing all $K_i$:

Comment: I don’t know whether it’s nonsense, but you clearly meant $K=k\left(\bigcup_iK_i\right)$, which to my mind is correct.

Comment: @Lukas so you mean that I need to write $k(\bigcup_{i\in I} K_i)$? Yes the I removed the direct product.

Comment: @Lukas if you have time I also posted another question about liftings which I don't understand the meaning and the idea behind it, maybe you can also take a look at it?

Comment: @aprozz Yes that is the notation I know for that kind of solution. The notation $k(\bigcup_{i \in I} K_i)$ shows that you take all elements of $K_i$ and adjunct them to $k$ - which is what we want to do.

Comment: @Lukas perfect thanks!